# Threedots showing as diamond question marks

Tags: html, joomla, encoding, character-encoding

I am working on [this website](http://goo.gl/xNupxe) and when I change the language to chinese, the treedots are changing to diamond question marks instead of showing three dots at the end of my slideshow. Can anyone tell me why is this happening and how can I fix it because in my Joomla template I have `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

P.S. I use Falang component for translation if that matters

Comment: Can you check to see if the slider uses `substr()` to cut the text? It should be somewhere in the main files of the slider.

Comment: A question should contain code needed to reproduce the problem. As asked, the question becomes rather meaningless after the live site has been fixed.

Comment: You should also specify what you mean by changing the language to chinese, which threedots or treedots you are referring to, and which browser you are using.

Comment: @ilias your comment have bringme to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used `mb_substr()` instead of `substr()` in the module code and that solve everything!